# how to represent parallel acitvities in use case diagram

Tags: uml

One of the use case is application has to support parallel activities. when user clicks on a button alogirthms should run in different threads,but each one is independent of each other.

It is possible to show using activity diagram. But wanted to know how parallel activities can be shown in use case diagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not show that on a use case diagram. Rather link a constraint to the use case telling that it must run concurrent.

You can model the behavior in an activity diagram which you can put inside the use case.